# BibLaTeX: sorting alphabetically with non-latin characters (Ś)

Tags: biblatex, indexing, unicode, sorting

Biblatex indexing works very well with latin names. But when an author has foreign name (Łukasiewicz) the Ł letter is changed to `\IeC {\L}` and `makeindex` is not able to sort it well. In Polish it should be placed after L and before M (AĄ...CĆ...EĘ...LŁ...NŃ...OÓ...SŚ...ZŹŻ).

The problem does not exist with titles indexing using:

```
   \DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{\index[tit]{#1}}
```

(As far as I understand the problem is related with `\protected@edef` in `\newbibmacro*`).

Probably in other languages someone can have similar problem and knows the solution how to put in the `idx` file

```
\indexentry {Łukasiewicz|hyperpage}{123}
```

Here is a small example of `a.tex` source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,indexing=true,,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{\index[tit]{#1}}
\bibliography{a}
\usepackage{index}
\newindex{default}{idx}{ind}{Index}
\newindex{tit}{tdx}{tnd}{Titles}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Xauthor,
  author = {Śauthor},
  title = {Śauthor's Book}
}
@Book{Sauthor,
  author = {Sauthor},
  title = {Sauthor's Book}
}
@Book{Tauthor,
  author = {Tauthor},
  title = {Tauthor's Book}
}
\end{filecontents}
\section*{Polish sort order ...SŚT...}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\printindex[default]
\printindex[tit]
\end{document}
```

and the small script

```
export LANG=pl_PL.utf8
latex a
biber a
latex a
makeindex -L a.idx -o a.ind
makeindex -L a.tdx -o a.tnd
latex a
xdvi a.dvi
```

In the `a.idx` we have problematic:
    \indexentry {\IeC {\'S}author}{1}
in `a.tdx` we have correct:
    \indexentry {Śauthor's Book}{1}
so we get correct order in `biber` (References) and Titles but wrong in Index (Śauthor is before Sauthor).

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Please consider changing your question title to something more specific like "BibLaTeX: sorting alphabetically with non-latin characters (Ł)". Here's some information on [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). And sorry we're all just discussing your question on a meta level, I personally don't use BibLaTeX, so I can't help you out, but I'm sure somebody will take on this question soon.

Comment: The title refers to biblatex, while the problem seems to be with the index. Makeindex is not able to work with extended character sets; you should consider xindy, for that purpose.

Comment: In this example we can see that `makeindex` is working well with `utf8` and `locales`. The problem is that `biblatex` is generating two types of `\indexentry`: one correct for titles (utf8) and the second using `IeC {...}` for names which creates problems. Because the general utf8 `biber` and `makeindex` behavior is correct, the problem is rather with `biblatex` which is inconsistent in this subject (generates two types of `\indexentry`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run your document with `xelatex` instead of `latex` with the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
```

`xelatex` has full utf8 support. It may also be a good idea to use `xindy` instead of `makeindex`. You can try:

```
texindy -L polish a.idx
texindy -L polish a.tdx -o a.tnd
```

have a look into the dpocumentation of `xindy`, it has a better language support than `makeindex`

Comment: Thank you. `xelatex` works well with `makeindex` (strange - `texindy` does not sort well with these commands; it loads `latin2` module). Other problem with `xelatex` is that now I get `** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...` for `\foreignlanguage{greek}{\textgreek{#1}}` classical greek; but on the `pdf` everything is OK.

Comment: @zeta0 You can try this approach:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406943/113926