# Properly sort index containing utf8 characters?

Tags: pdftex, indexing, unicode, sorting, imakeidx

If my input file is utf8 encoded, how to I create an index where the entries are properly sorted?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hello World\index{Gödel}\index{Galois}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

After compiling with `pdflatex` and `makeindex`, the entries show up with “Gödel” before “Galois”, which is wrong.

In another [somewhat related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/biblatex-sorting-alphabetically-with-non-latin-characters-s) it is suggested to compile with `xelatex` instead; however I'm trying to do this in a large-ish project already written by someone else, and trying to switch to xelatex is proving a bit problematic.

So, is there a way to make it work with `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `xindy` instead of `makeindex` I get the desired result. That is, instead of running

```
makeindex filename.idx
```

run

```
texindy filename.idx
```

Comment: Hmm.. the small example is working, but not when I try to apply it in my complete project. Will have to pinpoint the error and then come back.

Comment: You may have to specify the language and encoding. E.g. `texindy -L german -M lang/german/utf8 filename.idx`. (See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing#International_indexes )

Comment: Thanks! I just got it to work, there was a syntax error in one of my `\index` entries, and texindy was complaining with a weird error message. But now it's all working!