# xelatex biblatex russian indexing

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I use the `xelatex` with the `biblatex` package and with indexing author names. The `biber` works fine with bibliography of books in English and in Russian. The author index is generated. In the bibliography the order is correct but in the index of names I get bad order - Russian names does not follow the latin index names order. How can I correct it? Here is the `test.tex` example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{index}
\newindex{default}{idx}{ind}{My Index}
\newindex{titles}{tdx}{tnd}{My Titles}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,indexing=true,sorting=nty,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{\index[titles]{#1}}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Alma,
    author = {Alma, B.},
    title = {Test},
    year = {2000}
}
@INBOOK{Roma,
    author = {Рома, Ю.},
    title = {Oбраз},
    booktitle = {Материал},
    year = {2001},
    sortkey = {Roma}
}
@BOOK{Sama,
    author = {Sama, C.},
    title = {Last one},
    year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Testing}

Three \cite{Sama}.
Two \cite{Roma}.
One \cite{Alma}.

\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The References are almost OK (there are two dots after the `Рома, Ю`):

```
References
Alma, B. Test. 2000.
Рома, Ю.. “Oбраз”. In: Материал. 2001.
Sama, C. Last one. 2002.
```

But the index is not (by means of `makeindex test`):

```
My Index
Alma, B., 1
Sama, C., 1
Рома, Ю., 1
```

The `texindy test.idx` makes the same error:

```
A
Alma, B., 1
S
Sama, C., 1
Рома, Ю., 1
```

This is, of course, because in the `test.idx` we have
`\indexentry {Sama, C.}{1}
\indexentry {Рома, Ю.}{1}
\indexentry {Alma, B.}{1}
\indexentry {Alma, B.}{1}
\indexentry {Рома, Ю.}{1}
\indexentry {Sama, C.}{1}`

We should have there something like:
`\indexentry {Roma@Рома, Ю.}{1}`

because there is `sortkey = {Roma}` in the `bib` file for `biblatex`.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect the "bibencoding=inputenc" - biber will handle this as it converts to UTF-8 internally for sorting but for indexing, I suppose that depends on the indexing package you are using - like @egreg says, we need a MWE.

Comment: Have a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22785
I suspect that you need to be using `xindy` for UTF-8 indexing - then you could drop the `\textrussian`

Comment: I think in the end this comes down to the linked problem: you need to index using Xindy.