# Index sorting problem with Vietnamese

Tags: indexing, unicode, sorting, amsbook, listingsutf8

I use Texmker 4.1 and Texlive 2013 in my Xubuntu. I use this system to write my teacher's book with the AMS package (gsm in fact), which is in Vietnamese. There is a problem in sorting the index, it did not display the order correctly, and some indices were missed. I have searched on Tex Stack Exchange, there are indeed two topic about this kind of problem ( [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131334/how-to-sort-alphabet-index-in-vietnamese-correctly) and  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/properly-sort-index-containing-utf8-characters) ), but the solution there did not work in my case.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
This is the MWE

\index{Đồng biến}
\index{Nghịch biến}
\index{Dao động điều hòa}
\index{Ếch}
\index{Alphabetical}
\index{Albert Einstein}
\index{Bổ đề}
\index{Đường thẳng}
\index{Chương}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Makeindex command in the terminal will produce the Index sorting like this :

Ếch>Đồng biến>Đường thẳng>Albert Einstein>Alphabetical>Bổ đề>Chương>Dao động điều hòa>Nghịch biến.

This is not the sorting I want as in Vietnamese, it should be like this

Albert Einstein>Alphabetical>Bổ đề>Chương>Dao động điều hòa>Đồng biến>Đường thẳng>Ếch

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Both the questions you referenced recommend `xindy` rather than `makeindex` as `makeindex` is hard-coded for English. If those answers don't solve your problem, using `makeindex` certainly won't. It might be easier to say in what way those solutions didn't work. (For example, is the problem that you can't get `xindy` to work?)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot `xindy` did not work, I have said above. It removed the utf8 encoded like Ê, Đ. It also changed the header style of the Index page, therefore I asked the new question.

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh There's no point try to solve the problem using `makeindex`. It would be better if you edited your question to show how you tried to create the index using `xindy` (for example, did you use `xindy` directly or did you use `texindy` and what were the arguments). Also it might help if you added the contents of the `.idx` file (so we can see if the utf8 characters were correctly written to the index file) and the `.ilg` (so we can see if there were any error messages or warnings).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot -- i'm familiar with the `gsm` style.  it has an index page style that is quite "nonstandard" and incompatible with all index packages except for `amsmidx`.  (`amsmidx` was built to avoid messing up this special page layout, and at the moment, i am trying to devise a modification to `imakeidx` to correct the problem, since `imakeidx` is superior to `amsmidx`.)  it may be possible to patch `xindy` or `texindy` to fix the page layout problem with `gsm`, but otherwise the only (unpleasant) approach i can see is to insert sort fields for the index terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is that the `gsm` document class (based on `amsbook`) has a very
"nonstandard" page style.  (most other ams document classes based on `amsbook` do not
have quite as nasty a problem, but other problems may occur; `amsbook` hasn't been
tested, as far as i know, with `xindy` or `texindy`, and since it already contains
the basic `\index` commands, can't even be used with `makeidx`.)

although the workaround is, to say the least, unpleasant, `makeindex` *can* be used if
a sort field is added to every index term that doesn't sort where it is wanted.
for example:

```
\index{Dong bien@Đồng biến}
```

i am trying to work on the compatibility problem (specifically with `imakeidx`), but
as this hasn't actually been requested by an author writing a book for the ams, it
doesn't have high priority.  (assistance is also needed from the authors of the
affected packages, not always easy to get -- it's not high priority for then either).

Comment: What should I do if I want to sort the subentry?

Comment: Ah, it works. Thanks alot @barbara beeton :)