# Properly sort index containing utf8 characters? - Continuation

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I have a simple input file, in utf8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hello World\index{Gödel}\index{Galois}
\index{Álgebra}\index{Índice}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

when I process with

```
xelatex file.tex
texindy -L portuguese -M lang/portuguese/utf8 file.idx
```

I get the entries for Galois and Gödel sorted in proper order, but NOT the entries for Álgebra and Índice.

```
A
Álgebra, 1
Índice, 1
G
Galois, 1
Gödel, 1
```

it even places "Í" under the letter "A".

I am aware of this [not so similar question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/properly-sort-index-containing-utf8-characters).

I can't really run `xindy` because of incompatibility with `hyperref` as pointed [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing#International_indexes).

Is is possible to get `texindy` to sort the entries in proper order?

Comment: You *are* using xindy with texindy, texindy is simply a wrapper with some default options setup.

Comment: Seems there might be something wrong with the setup, if I use `texindy -L danish -C utf8` on the `.idx` file, the sorting is as I'd expect it A, G and I groups (testest on TL19 on linux)

Comment: @daleif Yes, I see it works. The command reccommended in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/properly-sort-index-containing-utf8-characters is wrong.