# Making and sorting index for Russian

Tags: xindy

Trying to make index with Russian words, MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Первая}

\index{notepad}
\index{apple}
\index{часть}
\index{дерево}
\index{электрон}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I use MiKTeX (full and updated), run: latexmk.exe -pdf file.tex

This gives me file.pdf with russian words in Index, but they are sorted in wrong way. file.idx is:

```
\indexentry{notepad}{1}
\indexentry{apple}{1}
\indexentry{\IeC {\cyrch }\IeC {\cyra }\IeC {\cyrs }\IeC {\cyrt }\IeC {\cyrsftsn }}{1}
\indexentry{\IeC {\cyrd }\IeC {\cyre }\IeC {\cyrr }\IeC {\cyre }\IeC {\cyrv }\IeC {\cyro }}{1}
\indexentry{\IeC {\cyrerev }\IeC {\cyrl }\IeC {\cyre }\IeC {\cyrk }\IeC {\cyrt }\IeC {\cyrr }\IeC {\cyro }\IeC {\cyrn }}{1}
```

And I see the problem is that LaTeX makes index according to these {\cyrch}, {\cyre} etc. I thought using utf8 encoding and xindy could solve all the problems with languages. How to make russian index with correct sorting: дерево, часть, электрон in my case?

Comment: I think that this post might contain your answer:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/biblatex-sorting-alphabetically-with-non-latin-characters-%C5%9A  I think that XeLaTeX has better multiple language support.

Comment: What options do you pass to `xindy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to some constraints, the `\index` command doesn't work very well with UTF-8 characters (something which could only be solved with a brand new version, I'm afraid.)

You can overcome the issue by doing

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Первая}

\rindex{notepad}
\rindex{apple}
\rindex{часть}
\rindex{дерево}
\rindex{электрон}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Calling

```
texindy -L russian -C utf8 <filename>.idx
```

produces the index as expected:

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer. But, sorry, doesn't work for me. I just used your MWE.

Comment: @Alx “Doesn't work” in the sense that your computer screen becomes flashy yellow or…

Comment: thank you for answer. But, sorry, doesn't work for me. I just used your MWE. `pdflatex 111.tex` gives 111.idx with the same `{\cyr}` symbols, i.e. not readable (no words in Russian). Then, as you suggested, `texindy -L russian -C utf8 111.idx`. This gives such error: `ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string` and 111.ind of zero length, so that running pdflatex again prints only first page with Chapter, but no Index at all. Does this concern with my MiKTeX distribution, or utf8? I could use another encoding (cp1251, eg.) if that helps ...

Comment: @Alx I'm very sorry: I left in a line I used for debugging. Try now.

Comment: OK, thanks, this works now! But, there is some difference in English and Russian parts of Index. I mean each Russian word (group of words) has corresponding first letter in bold before, and English words are printed in common list. Can all parts of Index (all languages) be printed in a similar way?

Comment: @Alx I don't think Xindy supports more than this. You should make two indices, I guess.

Comment: many tanks for your help. BTW, I just tried `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` (I saw @AFeldman pointing to similar topic about sorting non-latin characters) -- great, `latexmk -xelatex <file>.tex` makes Index with right sorting with my oroginal file (without your `\detokenize` block). Probably, I should use `xelatex` if I work with utf8.

Comment: I really wish that everything could be done in pdflatex, or using lualatex, because generally you can compile all your LaTeX code using lualatex, but not so with xelatex and microtype does not work well (still?) in xelatex.  But is seems there are some things that xelatex just is better suited for, like multiple language support.

Comment: Hi, getting this error with your setup: `ERROR: Could not find file "tex/inputenc/utf8.xdy"`

Comment: Ah! It works with this command `texindy -M lang/ukrainian/utf8-lang.xdy wrindex.idx`

Comment: How can I troubleshoot the error "ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string"? I did a search and, of course, I do not have any empty index entries. Is this tool lacking diagnostics, or is there a method to find exactly what it does not like?

Answer (score 4):

> OK, thanks, this works now! But, there is some difference in English and Russian parts of Index. I mean each Russian word (group of words) has corresponding first letter in bold before, and English words are printed in common list. Can all parts of Index (all languages) be printed in a similar way?

I managed this with changing the `\makeindex` command in egreg's answer to:

```
\makeindex [options = -L russian -C utf8 -M latin-alph.xdy]
```

Here for this command could work you should pass `-enable-write18` key to pdfLaTeX. Alternatively, you could run texindy manually passing `-M latin-alph.xdy` key to it.

Here `latin-alph.xdy` file should look like this:

```
(define-letter-groups
  ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m"
   "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"))

(require
  "rules/latin-tolower.xdy")

(use-rule-set
  :run 0
  :rule-set ("latin-tolower"))

(markup-letter-group
  :open-head "~n~n  \textbf {\Large "
  :close-head "}~n  \nopagebreak"
  :capitalize)
```

And the result is:

[image: Index]

Comment: I actually don't have any question, just improved the previous answer.

Comment: How to change this example to "latin first, cyrillic second"?

Comment: @andc, as I remember, by default, xindy sorts entries with latin letters first. So, just remove `-M latin-alph.xdy` option to `\makeindex`.

Answer (score 3):

> OK, thanks, this works now! But, there is some difference in English
>   and Russian parts of Index. I mean each Russian word (group of words)
>   has corresponding first letter in bold before, and English words are
>   printed in common list. Can all parts of Index (all languages) be
>   printed in a similar way?

Just one more improving.
You can use this simple solution.

```
(require "lang/english/utf8.xdy")
(require "lang/russian/utf8.xdy")

(define-sort-rule-orientations (forward backward forward forward))
(use-rule-set   
    :run 0
    :rule-set (
        "en-alphabetize" 
        "ru-alphabetize" 
        "en-ignore-special" 
        "ru-ignore-special"
    )
)   
(use-rule-set 
    :run 1
    :rule-set (
        "en-resolve-diacritics"  
        "ru-resolve-diacritics" 
        "en-ignore-special" 
        "ru-ignore-special"
    )
)
(use-rule-set 
    :run 2
    :rule-set (
        "en-resolve-case" 
        "ru-resolve-case" 
        "en-ignore-special"
        "ru-ignore-special"
    )
)
(use-rule-set 
    :run 3
    :rule-set (
        "en-resolve-special"
        "ru-resolve-special"
    )
)
```

Store this code to `multilingual.xdy`.
And run:

```
texindy -C utf8 -M multilingual.xdy -o you-paper.ind you-paper.idx
```

Note: You shouldn't pass language to `texindy` (i.e. `-L russian`.), because `multilingual.xdy` contains description of both languages.

> `\makeindex [options = -L russian -C utf8 -M latin-alph.xdy]`

If you prefer use `imakeidx` code will be

```
\makeindex [options = -C utf8 -M multilingual.xdy]
```

The result will be with latin-first sort order.
[image: result of multilingual.xdy]

By the way, you can change sort order. Just swap language instructions in `rule-sets`.

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: I keep getting "ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string" when I run texindy

Comment: why "Notepad" is before "Apple" in your example???