# Indexing slovenian language

Tags: indexing, languages

I am in trouble. I would like to organise index by texindy for slovenian language, but reactions are highly unstable.

If I use …

```
\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[intoc, columns=2, options= -s z.ind]{\fontsize{9pt}{2pt}\printindex} 

z.ind= 
(headings_flag 1 
heading_prefix "\n %\\normal %\\fontec \\noindent \\textbf{"heading_suffix "} %\\par \\nopagebreak \n")
```

[image]

Two days ago, all was OK, but now all is false again.
Nothing happened, even if I recompile many times. 
All Slovenian special characters (ČŠŽĆ) go under the Symbols. 
I can’t find some correct and stable solution over the internet.

Does anybody have any idea how to deal with index for Slovenian? ... except my apologies in footnotes?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass Xindy the language you're going to need for collation of the particular index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-L slovenian -C utf8]

\begin{document}

A\index{Altamira}

B\index{Babbage}

Č\index{Čeh}

Ž\index{Žvanut}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Egreg, Thanks a lot :-) it work well, Miran

Comment: @user102582 You owe me a drink when I'll come to Slovenia, favorite destination for my Saturday bike tours. `;-)`

Comment: so you are somwhere near? Absolutely :-)

Comment: @user102582 If you have time, you can join us in the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [russian index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292351/making-and-sorting-index-for-russian)

It works great for russian index, I've checked. I guess slovenian index will be ok too.

Comment: Also you can try `multilingual` index:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406943/113926