# Russian & English index via pdfLaTeX

Tags: indexing

I have MWE with index consisting of 2 parts - english and russian. Everything is ok, but I'd like to get  these 2 parts in another order, russian part of index firstly, then english part of index. Could anobody help?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Первая}

\rindex{notepad}
\rindex{something}
\rindex{thing}
\rindex{apple}
\rindex{яблоко}
\rindex{часть}
\rindex{дерево}
\rindex{электрон}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Another approach is to make 2 separate indexes without xindy, but now russian part has no rus. alphabetical order. How can I solve the problem?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
%\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[split]{splitidx}

%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\rindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
%  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
%}
%\makeatother

\makeindex

\newindex[Items engl]{idx}

\newindex[Русский]{aut}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Первая}

\sindex[aut]{Грин}
\sindex[aut]{Абрикос}
\sindex[aut]{Ломоносов}
\sindex[aut]{Волгоград}
\sindex[aut]{Яковлев}
\sindex[aut]{Пример}

\sindex[idx]{thing}
\sindex[idx]{apple}
\sindex[idx]{zip}
\sindex[idx]{bed}
\sindex[idx]{qwert}
\sindex[idx]{citer}

\printindex[aut]

\printindex[idx]

\end{document}
```

ОK, it seems I almost have the solution. I've separated 2 indexes, first is russian and sorted alphabetically, second is english, also sorted correctly, I used the package glossary there. Now I have to do some make up for english index (glossary)  - 1) to make russian title Список команд instead of Glossary, 2) make space between rows thinner and 3) make the font in english  glossary the same as in 1rst part. The best way is to help yourself, but I'll be happy if somebody give me useful idea(s).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[russian]{translator}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hypertoc=true,style=list]{glossary}

\renewcommand*\glossaryname{List}
\renewcommand\glossarytitle{} 

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\makeindex
\makeglossary

\begin{document}

\chapter{Первая}

\glossary{name={abba}, description={}}
\glossary{name={beta}, description={}}
\glossary{name={zeta}, description={}}
\glossary{name={wet}, description={}}
\glossary{name={qwert}, description={}}
\glossary{name={xenon}, description={}}

\rindex{Грин}
\rindex{Абрикос}
\rindex{Ломоносов}
\rindex{Волгоград}
\rindex{Яковлев}
\rindex{Пример}

\printindex

%\newpage
\chapter*{\glossaryname}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printglossary
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use to separate indexes, with `\index[russian]{...}` and `\index[english]{...}`?

Comment: If doesn't work unfortunately (now on my comp). Actually I used the example from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292351/making-and-sorting-index-for-russian but there is only one russian index. I'd like to get two.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer seems I got your idea, I can separate 2 index lisits now.  The problem is - russian index has no rus. alphabetical order. English index is alright.