# Expand argument for detokenize while creating index

Tags: expansion, detokenize

After reading this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292362/64189, i'm trying to use it for my index.

```
\newcommand{\ukindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}
```

But i need to call `\ukindex` with something like this

> \string лінійне програмування/ZZZZ{\string \textit {див. також}
>   \string цілочисельне лінійне програмування, 0-1 цілочисельне
>   програмування}

Actually this was excerpt from .idx file, but i need it to be expanded.

*EDIT:*
I add code as David asked

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=truexindy]

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\ukindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand{\seealso}[2]{%
  \indexas{\string#1/ZZZZ}{\string\textit{див. також} \string#2}%
}

\newcommand{\indexas}[2]{\begingroup\ukindex{#1{#2}[]}\endgroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\seealso{лінійне програмування}{цілочисельне лінійне програмування, 0-1 цілочисельне
програмування}

Blablabla said Nobody 
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: can't you just remove the `\string` from your `\seealso` definition? what else do you need to expand?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think `\textit`. Edited: oh sorry, i think you are right. I'll check on the real file.

Comment: `\texttit` isn't expandable, it causes italic fonts to be selected when typesetting but it can not expand to anything useful when writing the idx file.

Comment: Just remove all `\string` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove the `\string` commands,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=truexindy]

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\ukindex}[2][\imki@jobname]{%
  \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}%
}

\renewcommand{\seealso}[2]{%
  \indexas{#1/ZZZZ}{\textit{див. також} #2}%
}

\newcommand{\indexas}[2]{\begingroup\ukindex{#1{#2}[]}\endgroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\seealso{лінійне програмування}{цілочисельне лінійне програмування, 0-1 цілочисельне
програмування}

Blablabla said Nobody 
\printindex

\end{document}
```

the `.idx` file contains

```
\indexentry{лінійне програмування/ZZZZ{\textit {див. також} цілочисельне лінійне програмування, 0-1 цілочисельне програмування}[]}{1}
```

I'm not sure this is what you want, but at least there's no strange token.